# how to divide total score by score in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, math

how to divide total score by score in javascript ?

I have a code to display the total score of each criterion, and I want to display it in percentage form on a graph.

I have totalscore in criteria:

1. Criteria 1 : totalscore = 3
2. Criteria 2 : totalscore = 2

and the expected output should be displayed as a percentage to be

1. Criteria 1: percent = (3/5)*100 = 60%
2. Criteria 2: percent = (2/7)*100 = 40%

My Controller:

```
public function getChartSecurity()
{

    $result = DB::table('tbl_score_details')->select(DB::raw('sum(score) as totalscoreall'))->first();

    $result = DB::table('tbl_score_details')
                  ->join('tbl_criterias','tbl_criterias.id_criteria','tbl_score_details.criteria_id')
                  ->select('tbl_criterias.criteria_name', DB::raw("Sum(score) as totalscore "), DB::raw('sum(score) as totalscoreall'))
                  ->groupBy('criteria_name')
                  ->orderBy('totalscore', 'DESC')
                  ->get();

    return response()->json($result);
}
```

I'm trying to make two queries with the same variable, the first is to retrieve the total score and the second query is to retrieve the total score for each criterion. But this didn't work. TotalScoreAll is undefined in javascript

My Javascript:

```
var url = "{{ url('pengawas/chart_security') }}"
var Criteria   = new Array();
var TotalScore = new Array();
var TotalScoreAll = new Array();
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.get(url, function(response){
      response.forEach(function(data){
        Criteria.push(data.criteria_name);
        TotalScore.push(data.totalscore);

        console.log(data.totalscoreall);
      });

  });
});
```

Result when i tried
[image]

Please help me, thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and ***expected output*** using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: This first thing is to check if the controller is returning the correct data, but you haven't posted the code that actually creates the (I'm assuming) JSON. Also, what does the request look like in the network tab of the browsers debugger? Finally: Why don't you calculate the value in the controller, specifically in the SQL query? Databases are really good at calculating things like that.

Comment: i've tried calculating divide in controller using sql query, only query grouping returns values and query `$result = DB::table('tbl_score_details')->select(DB::raw('sum) (score) as totalscoreall'))->first();` does not return value